# Javascript function()

Tags: javascript

sorry for so newbie q. I have downloaded a sample js/css menu and it has js in the beginning /(function($) {/ so I have changed function to myfunction($) and replaced it. so after it still works but without effects. point me to that stuff is that function() thing so strict ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant section of your code before and after? This isn't enough to go on.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say you probably shouldn't be editing code if you have no idea how.

Comment: codecademy is good for this kind of thing: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: thanks! I know I have to learn how the world is ruled, before to try JS :)

Comment: give me a reply! I have replaced function($) to 123($), no deal, then I replaced 123($) back to function($) and have same. I promise I will read every char* on codecademy >

Answer (score 1):

In that context, `function` is a language feature that starts a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), while `myfunction` is a variable you (presumably) haven't defined (so if you look in your JavaScript console you should see an error message).

Comment: Dear, I'm stuck, when I replace it back to function($) I still get it no working. Tested it! The menu is here http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/flat-jquery-responsive-menu